# How can I only display links from a child category

Tags: categories

Using this code from the codex:

```
       <?php
$category = get_the_category();
if($category[0]){
echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>';
}
?>
```

Codex link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

I am able to display the category the post is in as a link (e.g. Business). However, I don't want to display the parent categories. I only want to display the child categories of a certain parent category.

My category structure is like this: Premium (Parent) > Premium Themes (Child) > Ecommerce (Child), Business (Child), Photography (Child), etc.

So I only want to display the children of the Premium Themes category.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

your code may look like

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
foreach( $category as $cat):
  if($cat[0]->parent == ' your_parent_category_id ( Premium )'){
   echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat[0]->term_id ).'">'.$cat[0]->cat_name.'</a>';
  break;
  }
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get that to work. But I've found a new snippet. Going to create a new thread so it's less confusing.

Comment: as i visit your new thread, i updated my answer.i think it works for you and in this you do not need to call any additional wordpress function.just insert id of parent category in `if` condition